# Base type on object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

First off - Sorry for the long explanation, but I am unsure how to make it clear enough what I want without it. But...I am making a Table component in React (with typescript). And I am thinking something similar to this:

```
const data = [
 { id: 1, name: "Peter", age: 43, country: "USA" },
 { id: 2, name: "Stewie", age: 2, country: "UK" },
 { id: 3, name: "Brian", age: 10, country: "Spain" },
]

<Table
  data={data}
  headers={[
    {
      title: 'Name',
      value: 'name'
    },
    {
      title: 'Age (In Years)',
      value: 'age'
    },
  ]} />
```

So I wanted to make sure that the selected value is limited to the props of the original data. Which I did with this interface:

```
interface HeaderData<ItemKey> {
  accessor: ItemKey;
  title: string;
}

interface Props<Item> {
  data: Array<Item>;
  headers: Array<HeaderData<keyof Item>>;
}
```

Which works brilliantly. So now comes the problem. I wanted to include the ability to add a new row. So for that to happen I am rendering a text box for each column and I want to keep track of the data entered for the columns using a useState. So I could just write the following:

```
const [data, setData] = useState<Partial<Item>>({});
```

And then set data as I go. But I really would love to base the data object on the headers so that if the headers are only name and age like in the example. I'd only have a data object of { name: string, age: string }

So essentially the useState default value is:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(
  headers.reduce((curr, next) => ({ ...curr, [next.value]: "" }), {})
);
```

When I look at what the typescript interprets this into {} - But when I later try to access it using data[header.value] it complains

```
Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type '{}'.
```

and it does not help if I do: data[header.value.toString()] or something like that neither.

What type do I need to set to put a constraint on "data" so that I only get the "header" values?

Thanks for reading ;)

EDIT: Thanks @JonathanHamel for pointing out a glaring mistake. But the type question still remains.

Comment: Should it be `useState({headers: headers.map(...)})` ? (note the `headers` attribute) from seeing the above example, `data` is of type Item, not an array

Comment: @JonathanHamel No I shouldn't think so - Cause I want to create an object with attributes names after the "value"...value. I.e. { name: "", age: "" } - So I am not sure why the { headers: <...> } should be there? But maybe I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: You are currently returning an array of objects with a single key from the `.map` function, not an object with multiple keys. Logging your results with now would be `[{name: ""}, {age: ""}]`. Consider a `reduce`, perhaps.

Comment: @JonathanHamel Oh you are right! Wow can't believe i missed that. Thanks. I'll see if that does anything

Comment: @JonathanHamel So that solved one problem. So I would do something like this: ```const [newData, setNewData] = useState(headers.reduce((curr, next) => ({ ...curr, [next.accessor]: "" }), {}));``` - But is there a way that I can with the type reflect that I have "name" and "age" in there. So that I get some type help with I press write dot.

Comment: I think you need to add an assertion on the initial accumulator value you pass to `reduce` as otherwise Typescript infers that the reduce will return the `{}` type which causes your issue. So you need something like `headers.reduce((curr, next) => { ...}, {} as Something)` (not sure what `Something` should be exactly from your example, hopefully it's clear to you - otherwise I'll need to dive in to understand it better)

Comment: @cdimitroulas I agree that I need an inital assertion - but my whole issue is. How can I take a dynamic object like headers and convert it into a type (if that is even possible, I am not sure) - But I would settle with the object being converted to something like ```{ [keyof T]: string }```. But that's not possible either.

Comment: I've written an answer because it was too complicated to fit in a comment :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my understanding of your problem. Your initial data set includes four properties `id`, `name`, `age`, and `country`.  Your table only displays two of those properties: `name` and `age`.  You want to be able to add rows to the table and require that added object only need the two visible properties `name` and `age` instead of all four.

If `Item` is the whole object then the visible portion is `Pick<Item, 'name' | 'age'>`.  But we want to be able to infer which properties are picked from the `headers` object.  So we will use a generic `K extends keyof Item` to describe the visible columns.  Our `data` just needs the visible properties `Pick<Item, K>`.

Edited per your comment: the state of the rows will be stored outside the table, but the state of the row which we are creating by clicking "Add" will be stored inside the table.  All of the values of the added row will be in `string` format due to the limitations of the `input` component.  So the added row is an object with the keys `K` and the values `string` which is `Record<K, string>`.

```
interface HeaderData<ItemKey> {
    accessor: ItemKey;
    title: string;
}

interface Props<Item, K extends keyof Item> {
    data: Array<Pick<Item, K>>;
    headers: Array<HeaderData<K>>;
    onAddRow: (row: Record<K, string>) => void;
}

const Table = <Item, K extends keyof Item>({ data, headers, onAddRow }: Props<Item, K>) => {
    // create a new row object with empty string properties matching the header accessors
    // need to assert type or else it thinks the keys are just string
    const emptyRow = Object.fromEntries(headers.map(h => [h.accessor, ""])) as Record<K, string>;

    // the contents of the add row section
    const [nextRow, setNextRow] = useState(emptyRow);
    // whether or not add row section is expanded
    const [isAdding, setIsAdding] = useState(false);

    const onClickAdd = () => {
        // enter edit mode
        setIsAdding(true);
    }

    const onClickSave = () => {
        // push changes to parent
        onAddRow(nextRow);
        // exit edit mode
        setIsAdding(false);
        // reset nextRow
        setNextRow(emptyRow);
    }

    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    {headers.map(header => (
                        <th scope="col">{header.title}</th>
                    ))}
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {data.map(row => (
                    <tr>{/**... */}</tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
};

export const Test = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(initialData);

    const onAddRow = ({ name, age }: { name: string; age: string }) => {
        setData(data => [...data, {
            name,
            // convert string to number
            age: parseInt(age),
            // fill in missing properties
            country: "USA",
            id: -1,
        }])
    }

    return (
        <Table
            data={data}
            headers={[
                {
                    title: 'Name',
                    accessor: 'name'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Age (In Years)',
                    accessor: 'age'
                },
            ]}
            onAddRow={onAddRow}
        />
    )
}
```

I'm actually a bit surprised that the above code gets proper inference since our types don't require that `headers` is exhaustive (so `K` could be just `keyof Item` and not a subset).  But it seems to work!

The `Table` element in `Test` is getting the types inferred as:

- `Item`: `{ id: number; name: string; age: number; country: string; }`
- `K`: `"name" | "age"`

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAERSoYsDcAsAFD80EAHaF4wYcBjAUAGwAiFFHAC8cANr8423HGAATAFxwAjNmEoQSYywAKSSlBbYUAc2twALAGZsQ-MIwUACeNgCqJACCLDSYWjp4BsYATOaWHixkSADuwEjOcG4eqXD+gSHhANIx1HF8OrpJcL5wFlY2AEJQMsIFRcYmAAx+EAFBoawkYCgSNXUAuvxLfBKOdOhUABKo+khQiuQAPACSlCCVSMEAfLjx2uhoSISE0ManSOeXvPU60jCyHjE3WErm+1GWqz260ecFsjDAhBOZ2wlTgSAAHpRhPpCHAANaXCB0ODvEA3HB3OD6JTGSJQKAoYKHWzANB4pEfFFXK7fBoACx2e0ItPpjMO2xQu32SkOlW5vJ0Iki+n0CAg2WMAApGBrEEghFB9LLsECJK4rgBKVQ3ABuEAMYOWQlE8AAKigAEYA1RwDkgFFozFIbG4gnBIkks5XTV4ankbACyVC7BKlVq7I0YxwiAIv1cq0qcmUgD0xdK7AoVGUwhycB1cAgHoAVvr4LkYHy0eAYME4KaQXAwPC9tInnAQBQ0HyzXAO1RE1LCmhHs9oIQS2Wa0h9LOIIVniPZ8EwFRoGjZMQ9PAOxI8bi5-jLriUOw4E2iPB+65Kc6xF2wD26Y+gA8s2rYAHQMEwACi5R5IQmoLkK4ETmAiHWhofLgQ8TwvFA2AsCw8wWlaKC4sgBpGpUJpBGaPLLA0pazgKpQiFiMC4hGD6Sju9bEBgwAiD+Ih-uoNaYumJoOAAchiMDpvMPpEKQ5CUJqHwAcE6YWgq2hMdkApzlADbGcIEDwDxdbqn2raCcIei4hi0zYtuwkuhowCEMq+hmlJMDHF5KpmopajKWQlaausF5IDpDE6L+8AiAAwrIrJ4t5PqagWRY-A0ellsGjhoj58AgBAuyUg0xD+YFPkgpqQT4DFuk0HF2gJQ2wgpWlJAoDaVBqFlGEUrleVMWARCdlOKAgmOMB7tM7CBJVirCN56aauJ8nqrFo2MQV6JSMVR1lRVe06NVAXeWakVyMQu15ToTHsNVrRyemK3aNVskSeq6ndlpO0teCAijewMD4FA9map9vrkF6SBXLDDSHHOkpI+dj0o0EGNY3jeU4EhUCEChKBoUTGEw5j+N46jnaEEIJ4qCwQiyCwVyE4KUDgX8ALUIcxYdrjNP4yRIMi3lAs48jOhSwuws06jHrldcMuPTgcYoKTaH1oWcBUxLtM4zgxYAFSm+BltwKbxb84LUAK4bYtq76gvK-oqvU1LnoAo7Fr8NQ3z8E50DwB1rpPPAg3ZbcoMNB16ia35BwoCFBDEOFakSFIMgKEou1uX+qaqtZg14G0SAuO4ma6BXxhflwhTuPXtEDtQMcjXj1Up5qmsYeolvgUnscSxXdQS0xzr9bAfat64u6tPgIAensLv9IOL7EMcgSakUFrjyLTF0MAsiyHo9kgJ5hAzkOOYjvBLtlOM4RRM4LtNAAtGYsPUMRlIg5ScGkNoaw0OO6BGLtNYqA1kocWIsiaEGgZoameNO6G0erzDwAByaS6QsEH3QQ0HCq4oDGCwRXLBLsGi1CoQkWhGCpAAjIZEaumpt5wAAJqoGJhafB9C8rELwmQoolCUFYxoWI7Q8w4E02LumaBcj1QyLGn7AOywgA)

Comment: First off - Thanks for an awesome solution - I think it's nearing something - So when you are entering data into some textboxes at the bottom of the table, that data needs to be saved to an object which has the properties K ("name" | "age") but with string values. I.e. { name: "", age: "" } - So the table itself keeps track of the entered data. But when you then click "save" on the "add" row - You'll call a function that is passed to <Table> which will (if I understand your example correctly) have the data Pick<Item, K>

Comment: Ok if the added rows are always `string` then it would be something like `onAddRow: (row: Record<K, string>) => void;`  I'm going to play with this more.

Comment: I am learning so much today - Record<K, string> did the trick - That's amazingly useful - Thank you so very much! :)

Comment: That's really great - Thanks again - I didn't think it was possible to do what I wanted. But the solution is elegant and easy to implement :)

Comment: I've been looking your solution and I am hoping that you might be able to give me an answer on this. I could remove the "K extends keyof T" and just replace all references to K to "keyof T". But then obviously typescript would then infer the "onAddRow: (row: Record<keyof T, string>) => void;"  to the entire T object (all props) and not limit them to the headers as per your example.

But how do I recognize going forward that I need to add a second type that extends in order to get this behaviour? I'm not in fact exactly sure how typescript knows to limit to the specified headers?

Comment: When you have a generic function like `Table` then values for the generics `Item`(`T`) and  `K` are evaluated at the time that you **call** the function based on the arguments that you call it with.  So you can have different instances of `Table` with different `K` types.  In this case Typescript evaluates that `K` is `"name" | "age"` based on the array provided to the `headers` prop (think of the props of your JSX element like function arguments).  We know that we want a subset of the original object.  This sort of thing can be easier to see if you are dealing with a keyed object instead...

Comment: ...of an array because an array doesn't require completeness.  So your `headers` would still be "correct" even if `K` is `keyof T`.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mA76Rw) there is a mismatch in the `K` type between the `headers` and `onAddRow` so you get an error.  By using a keyed object it becomes more clear that we are dealing with a **subset** of the properties of `T`.  Otherwise we would need to be providing headers for every property.

Comment: Fantastic - Thank you so much :) It's really helpful information

Answer (score 0):

If your data and headers are dynamic like this, you can't know what the types are going to be statically (other than that the header values will be `string` of course).

For dynamic data, generally you want to extend from something like `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`. In this case you may wish to enforce that there is always an `id` field which is a `number` - in which case you can extend from `Record<PropertyKey, unknown> & { id: number }`.

Then your headers type would extend from `Record<keyof Omit<Row, "id">, string>`

This is what I came up with after playing around with it:

```
type Row<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> = T & { id: number }

type TableHeaders<T extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> =
  Record<keyof Omit<Row<T>, "id">, string>

type ExampleItem = { name: string; age: number; country: string }

type ExampleRow = Row<ExampleItem>

const data: ExampleRow[] = [
 { id: 1, name: "Peter", age: 43, country: "USA" },
 { id: 2, name: "Stewie", age: 2, country: "UK" },
 { id: 3, name: "Brian", age: 10, country: "Spain" },
]

declare const exampleHeaders: TableHeaders<ExampleRow>
// { name: string, age: string; country: string }

// To bring it back to your props interface, it may look like this:
interface Props<Item extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>> {
  data: Array<Row<Item>>;
  headers: TableHeaders<Item>;
}

declare const props: Props<ExampleItem>
```

Here's a playground link:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwDwBUoQB7AgOwCYDOsEAxnAE55IAK5ck5oA0hCADRQCuOA1jojgB8gqAF4oaAGRQA3lACWeAFxQcnALYAjCOSgBfAFAHQkCQENNAGwgAJCGbw6CqdFlyFiZSjToNmrDm4+AWExTwoqHlY4ADMoAHl1eWAkeGQUQQ4AIkUszKgCYHJ5HABzQSMTaABRDDN1MGsASWx1MLkceogVQuKygG4oM1Lu1Q1tckGybiKQHqKS0v1K8Bq6hus0sLSkWvrGiBaIdQqDMhxCqDwzYDMVPY2INIBtAF0w54NZBWUoAEYOJ11KMstQINhyFkOMNRgAWADMHGmOFmKiyAFUAMoAQSy+jYXzkihUACZAV00ZjsAh5BAoUMRqSkXAZuQ5lAMUw8XoCd9iVBEaoKRyAELFMw4ekwlR-AAMzNZ7KymLAZhK3IJryMjhIljM5Gg50umH21jsDicKhQFjN9kc5GcDwOaREAHpXd8gaNeotoYyCgsBlBkaiA30loYDEA

Comment: Thank you very much for giving it a shot :) Linda was able to suggest a solution where I could use Record to build my subset object :)